# LINQ - Convert List to Dictionary with Value as List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a

```
List<MyObject>
```

that I retrieve from the database. However, I would like it keyed by a property in MyObject for grouping purposes. What is the best way with LINQ to cast my list to:

```
Dictionary<long, List<MyObject>>
```

I have the following:

```
myObjectList.ToDictionary(x => x.KeyedProperty)
```

But it returns:

```
Dictionary<long, MyObject>
```

Comment: You want the dictionary keyed to a propery of WHICH MyObject? -- you have a whole list of them....

Answer (score 246, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group the `MyObject` instances by `KeyedProperty` and put that grouping into a `Dictionary<long,List<MyObject>>`.  If so then try the following

```
List<MyObject> list = ...;
var map = list
  .GroupBy(x => x.KeyedProperty)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Answer (score 18):

You should use the [`ToLookup` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) on the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) like so:

```
List<MyObject> list = ...;

ILookup<long, MyObject> lookup = list.ToLookup(o => o.KeyedProperty);
```

If you want to place that in a dictionary, then you could use the [`ToDictionary` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), like so:

```
IDictionary<long, IEnumerable<MyObject>> dictionary = lookup.ToDictionary(
    l => l.Key);
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the accepted answer? Does the `ILookup` preserve references whereas the accepted answer does not?

Comment: @PatPeter The idea is that when you have a one-to-many relationship between the key and the items, a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` may be a better structure than a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @PatPeter i would say the ILookup is the better structure to use (its like multimap to dictonary's map, if you know C++ collection algorithms) but it has one big factor to bear in mind - the lookup created is immutable. You cannot add or remove entries afterwards.

Comment: The other consideration is that even though `ILookup` is often the ideal in-code structure, it often isn't handled well for serialization.