# Create c# dynamic object from elements of a list

Tags: c#

how to convert : 
A List :

```
var list = new List<string>(){"str1","str2"}
```

to a anonymous object :

```
var anonymousObject = new {str1 = "str1",str2 = "str2"}
```

during runtime

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Just use a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: i'm trying to join two data tables using lambda expressions.
when i have to join on a single column its easy and it looks like this
<code>
Table1.Join(Table2,
leftTable => leftTable["joincolumn"],
rightTable => rightTable["joincolumn"],
(leftTable,rightTable) => new {leftTable,rightTable}
)
</code>

But i have an list in place of "joinColumn" and this needs to be handled using a dynamic object 
<code> new {column1=leftTable.column1,column2=leftTable.column2} </code>
and my list has column1 and column2

Comment: Do you want to slice `List` items into object of two properties?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549103/linq-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-value-as-list   check this link

Comment: i'm trying to join two data tables using lambda expressions. 
when i have to join on a single column its easy and it looks like this 
`Table1.Join(Table2, leftTable => leftTable["joincolumn"], rightTable => rightTable["joincolumn"], (leftTable,rightTable) => new {leftTable,rightTable} ) ` 
But i have an list in place of "joinColumn" and this needs to be handled using a dynamic object 
`new {column1=leftTable.column1,column2=leftTable.column2}` 
and my list has column1 and column2

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. `dynamic` has a specific meaning in C#, but is not really what you seem to be trying to do (and wouldn't make sense if it were). You _seem_ to be trying to create an instance of an anonymous type, but how specifically is unclear. The code you posted is insufficient in detail to understand the _general_ problem you are trying to solve; there are too many possible ways to accomplish literally what you're describing.

Comment: Yes sorry it is an anonymus object

Comment: The issue is that i have a list of columns on which I want to join in runtime

Comment: So i cant specifically hardcode the properties of the anonymous object since i dont know how many columns and what columns i need to join on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ExpandoObject which will give you the feature of dynamic type.

```
        var list = new List<string>() { "str1", "str2" };
        ExpandoObject obj = new ExpandoObject();
        var store = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;

        list.ForEach(x => store.Add(x, x));

        dynamic lst  = obj;
        var val = lst.str1; // Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use extension method represented below (from [here](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/05/idictionarystring-object-to-expandoobject-extension-method/)).

Because converting list to dynamic object by iterating on items manually can be painful when there is many situations like this in your application.

You can use this extension method like this:

```
  dynamic list = new List<string>() { "str1", "str2" }
       .ToDictionary(dd => dd, dd => (object)dd)
       .ToExpando();
```

The extension method:

```
    public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;

        // go through the items in the dictionary and copy over the key value pairs)
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            // if the value can also be turned into an ExpandoObject, then do it!
            if (kvp.Value is IDictionary<string, object>)
            {
                var expandoValue = ((IDictionary<string, object>)kvp.Value).ToExpando();
                expandoDic.Add(kvp.Key, expandoValue);
            }
            else if (kvp.Value is ICollection)
            {
                // iterate through the collection and convert any strin-object dictionaries
                // along the way into expando objects
                var itemList = new List<object>();
                foreach (var item in (ICollection)kvp.Value)
                {
                    if (item is IDictionary<string, object>)
                    {
                        var expandoItem = ((IDictionary<string, object>)item).ToExpando();
                        itemList.Add(expandoItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemList.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                expandoDic.Add(kvp.Key, itemList);
            }
            else
            {
                expandoDic.Add(kvp);
            }
        }

        return expando;
    }
```