# Join 3 tables where image exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to do an loop in my MVC5 app controller to get all timeline post and if Picture was uploaded in the post display the picture(s).

The code below get all the post and images but if i uploaded 3 pictures same post it will be looped out 3 times.

Is this not the correct way to go?

```
var query = (from i in db.Timeline

         join u in db.Users on i.UserId equals u.Id

         join f in db.UserFiles on i.Id equals f.TimelineId into ps
         from f in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()

         orderby i.PostDate descending
         select new { i.Id, i.UserId, i.Post, i.PostDate, u.FirstName, u.ProfilePic, FileName = f == null ? "No image(s)" : f.FileName + "_thumb." + f.FileExtension }).ToList();

List<TimelineLoop> cModel = new List<TimelineLoop>();

foreach (var item in query)
{
    cModel.Add(new TimelineLoop
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        UserId = item.UserId,
        Post = item.Post,
        PostDate = item.PostDate,
        Name = item.FirstName,
        ProfilePic = item.ProfilePic,

        FileName = item.FileName

    });
}
return cModel;
```

Comment: If you groupby filename then you only have to upload image once per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If I look at this particular part of your query, it would produce:

   ```
    from i in db.Timeline
    join u in db.Users on i.UserId equals u.Id
   ```

   timelinePost1 | user1

   timelinePost2 | user1

   timelinePost3 | user2

   => 1 user can have more than 1 timeline post.
2. After joining with the query below, the result in `1` will be joined to `UserFiles`. I assume that one timeline post can have many pictures. If you upload 3 pictures to the same post, you would expect something like this:

   ```
    join f in db.UserFiles on i.Id equals f.TimelineId into ps
    from f in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
   ```

   It produces:

   timelinePost1 | user1 | photo1

   timelinePost1 | user1 | photo2

   timelinePost1 | user1 | photo3

   timelinePost2 | user1 |

   timelinePost3 | user2 |

Do you get this pattern in the output?

EDIT:

if you want to have 1 object per post in your result, you may need to convert the `query` list into dictionary, which can be done similar to query below.

```
      List<MyObject> list = ...;
      var map = list
     .GroupBy(x => x.KeyedProperty)
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Reference: [LINQ - Convert List to Dictionary with Value as List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549103/linq-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-value-as-list)

Comment: Yes i get this pattern in the output.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can check for more information how to get all images for 1 post, without repetition. I hope this is what you are looking for