# C# - Convert List to Dictionary with Value as List

Tags: c#

So i read this [LINQ - Convert List to Dictionary with Value as List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549103/linq-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-value-as-list) but am not able to get it working.

According to that post, I should be able to convert a list of items where several of them have the same key to a dictionary <int, List<>)

```
List<MyObject> list = ...;
var map = list
  .GroupBy(x => x.KeyedProperty)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

I have

```
MyObject
{
   int OwnerId { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
}

List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

Now I want a dictionary with all objects that have the same OwnerId.

```
Dictionary<int, List<MyObjects> myObjects = ...
```

I tried to do

```
myObjects.GroupBy(x => x.OwnerId).ToDictionary(x => x.OwnerId, x => x.ToList());
```

problem is GroupBy returns a IGrouping<int, MyObject> and IGrouping does not have a property  OwnerId. What did I miss?

Comment: `.Key` will give you Common OwnerId in the `IGrouping`

Comment: Look at the difference for the first argument of ToDictionary in your first and second code example. One is `x.Key`, the other is `x.OwnerId`.

Comment: `  var res= myObjects.GroupBy(x => x.OwnerId).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.ToList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.Key` instead of `.OwnerId` when you are creating a dictionary.

```
var resultantDictionary = myObjects
      .GroupBy(x => x.OwnerId)
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
                        //^^^^ use .Key instead of .OwnerId
```

Comment: Ah, of course!  How could I miss that! Thank you very much!